# Datetime format convert to monthyear in excel

Tags: excel, csv

I have a questions about excel.

Excel sheet1 has data like below

```
OrderDate
2016-04-30T12:30:05
2016-05-03T05:14:09
2016-05-05T03:21:12
2016-05-06T07:03:24
2016-05-06T16:10:44
2016-05-07T01:12:33
2016-05-07T05:29:30
2016-05-08T06:17:05
```

Based on above data I want to show month and year and filter format and in the  next column outputlike below

```
OrderDate              | FInalOrderdate
2016-04-30T12:30:05    | April2016
2016-05-03T05:14:09    | May 2016
2016-05-05T03:21:12    | May 2016
2016-05-06T07:03:24    | May 2016
2016-05-06T16:10:44    | May 2016
2016-05-07T01:12:33    |May 2016
2016-05-07T05:29:30    |May 2016
2016-05-08T06:17:05    |May 2016
```

Here I need to to give filter in finalorderdate column if I want to show may month data then it should show only may month data.

How to achive this task in excel file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

1. Go to **Menu->Data->Data Tools->Text to Columns**
2. Click **Next**. Type  **"T"** on **Others**
3. Click **Finish**.
4. Format the column using **Format Cells** on **Custom** using '**mmm yyyy**. Just right click.
5. Go to **Menu->Data->Sort & Filter->Filter**

Comment: you want to use `mmmm yyyy`, `mmm yyyy` will show month abbreviations, ie 'Apr' not 'April'

Comment: +1 Also, you'll want to make a copy of the original data since **Text to Columns** will not retain it, as you indicate in your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,6,2),MID(A2,9,2))
```

in B2 and copied down to suit (assuming `OrderDate` is in A1).

Format as `mmmm yyyy`.

This preserves your source data and the day sequence within month, though without displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

Convert the value to a "real" Excel date

```
 B2:  =--SUBSTITUTE(A2,"T"," ")
```

Then, fill down and format as `mmmm yyyy`

This preserves the entire date/time stamp `B` but only displays the parts you want.

If you use the Data ► Filter, you will see the ability to select a month by its name, but you will also have the ability to drill down to dates, or times.